# Unknown prop `disableFocusRipple` on <div> tag. Material + GoogleAutocomplete

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, material-ui

I use

```
<GooglePlaceAutocomplete/>
```

from 'material-ui-autocomplete-google-places'. 
It works as intended but console says in red 
"Unknown prop `disableFocusRipple` on div tag"
I tried to shut it down in diff ways, none of them removes warning:
**1)** As React docs says https://reactjs.org/warnings/unknown-prop.html

```
const {disableFocusRipple, ...rest} = props;
<GooglePlaceAutocomplete {...rest}/>
```

**2)** As Material UI says

```
<GooglePlaceAutocomplete disableFocusRipple={true}/>
```

**3)**  As I found on the Web.

```
componentDidMount(){
   GooglePlaceAutocomplete.defaultProps.disableFocusRipple = true;
 }
```

**4)** I tried to remove

```
<ErrorBoundary>
```

wrapper at the root component.
 Please, I'd like to get know:
 1) What is disableFocusRipple and why it behaves in such a way?
 2) How to get rid of that warning text?